# ANDROID : IPTABLES how to block application making internet connection

Tags: android, linux-kernel, iptables

There does not seem to be any information on this topic.

I would like to find how I can use IPTABLES in Android to block an application making a connection.

So far I have:

1) Recompiled the Goldfish kernel and made sure NETFILTERS is enabled.
2) Start emulator using the new kernel.

I create a chain like :

```
/system/bin/iptables -N myChain
```

Check to make sure it is added

```
/system/bin/iptables -L
```

everything is good.

I can create a rule like:

```
iptables -A myChain -s 65.65.65.65 -j DROP
```

but how do I now create a rule a to block an application ?

I have tried things like:

```
iptables -A myChain -m owner --uid-owner 100013 -j DROP
```

but does not work I get error like : iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.

Does anyone know what I can try ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the problem is to recompile the Android kernel and make sure that the MATCH rule for IPFILTERS is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

100013 NOT 10013. it was not correct.

try  IPT="/system/xbin/iptables_armv5"

```
$IPT -S >/system/xbin/3.log
```

====================3.log===============

```
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-N afwall
-N afwall-3g
-N afwall-lan
-N afwall-reject
-N afwall-vpn
-N afwall-wifi
-A OUTPUT -j afwall 
-A afwall -p udp -m owner --uid-owner root -m udp --dport 53 -j RETURN 
-A afwall -d 194.126.240.3/32 -j RETURN 
-A afwall -o rmnet+ -j afwall-3g 
-A afwall -o rmnet0+ -j afwall-3g 
-A afwall -o rmnet1+ -j afwall-3g 
-A afwall -o rmnet2+ -j afwall-3g 
-A afwall -o pdp+ -j afwall-3g 
-A afwall -o rmnet_sdio+ -j afwall-3g 
-A afwall -o rmnet_sdio0+ -j afwall-3g 
-A afwall -o rmnet_sdio1+ -j afwall-3g 
-A afwall -o uwbr+ -j afwall-3g 
-A afwall -o wimax+ -j afwall-3g 
-A afwall -o vsnet+ -j afwall-3g 
-A afwall -o ccmni+ -j afwall-3g 
-A afwall -o ccmni0+ -j afwall-3g 
-A afwall -o qmi+ -j afwall-3g 
-A afwall -o svnet0+ -j afwall-3g 
-A afwall -o wwan+ -j afwall-3g 
-A afwall -o wwan0+ -j afwall-3g 
-A afwall -o cdma_rmnet+ -j afwall-3g 
-A afwall -o usb+ -j afwall-3g 
-A afwall -o usb0+ -j afwall-3g 
-A afwall -o pdp0+ -j afwall-3g 
-A afwall -o eth+ -j afwall-wifi 
-A afwall -o wlan+ -j afwall-wifi 
-A afwall -o tiwlan+ -j afwall-wifi 
-A afwall -o eth0+ -j afwall-wifi 
-A afwall -o ra+ -j afwall-wifi 
-A afwall -o wlan0+ -j afwall-wifi 
-A afwall-3g -m owner --uid-owner app_11 -j RETURN 
-A afwall-3g -m owner --uid-owner app_13 -j RETURN 
-A afwall-3g -m owner --uid-owner app_21 -j RETURN 
-A afwall-3g -m owner --uid-owner app_24 -j RETURN 
-A afwall-3g -m owner --uid-owner app_73 -j RETURN 
-A afwall-3g -m owner --uid-owner app_88 -j RETURN 
-A afwall-3g -j afwall-reject 
-A afwall-reject -m limit --limit 1000/min -j LOG --log-prefix "{AFL}" --log-uid 
-A afwall-reject -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable 
-A afwall-wifi -d 192.168.0.100/32 -j RETURN 
-A afwall-wifi -m owner --uid-owner dhcp -j RETURN 
-A afwall-wifi -m owner --uid-owner wifi -j RETURN 
-A afwall-wifi -m owner --uid-owner app_11 -j RETURN 
-A afwall-wifi -m owner --uid-owner app_13 -j RETURN 
-A afwall-wifi -m owner --uid-owner app_21 -j RETURN 
-A afwall-wifi -m owner --uid-owner app_24 -j RETURN 
-A afwall-wifi -m owner --uid-owner app_73 -j RETURN 
-A afwall-wifi -m owner --uid-owner app_88 -j RETURN 
-A afwall-wifi -j afwall-reject
```